# Get a var with Selected Option in HTML downlist to Google Script Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I really need help I almost finish my google script but I am in trouble I do not how to get the selected option(month selected) from the downlist (html) and storage in a "var", I really appreciate your help.

I tried with getElementById without success.

Thank You.

> Document Code.gs

```
/*** Retrieves all the rows in the active spreadsheet that contain data and logs the values for each row.
   * For more information on using the Spreadsheet API, see
   * https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_spreadsheet*/

function Menu() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
       .createMenu("Christian's Menu")
       .addItem('Side Bar Comites', 'showSidebar')
       .addToUi();
 }

function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setTitle('Sedesol - Captura de Entregas')
      .setWidth(250);
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .showSidebar(html);
}

function autowritemonthday(form){
   var storeMonth = getElementById('monthlist').value; /*Does not work i dont know why*/
   Browser.msgBox(storeMonth); /*tried to view the value from var storeMonth*/

 /*I put this as comment because does not work either
    var e = document.getElementById('monthlist');
    var val = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;*/

/*I need Storage the selected value from the downlist here before the   onSeach(form)*/

   onSearch(form); /*call the function to search the input text and put the cursor in the right Cell*/
   var hoja = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = hoja.getSheets()[0];
   var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
   var ss = hoja.getActiveCell()
   var selectedrow = ss.getRow();
   var selectedcol = ss.getColumn();
   var monthpos = sheet.getRange(selectedrow, 7); /* get the cell position for example monthpost(5,7)*/
   var daypos = sheet.getRange(selectedrow, 8);
   var tempm = form.mesinini; /*get the value of the inputbox by NAME*/
   var tempd = form.dias;
   var remspacestxtmonth = tempm.trim(); /*remove blank spaces*/ 
   var uppertxtmonth = remspacestxtmonth.toUpperCase();/*conv. to uppercase*/
   var remspacestxtday = tempd.trim(); /*remove blank spaces*/ 
   monthpos.setValue(uppertxtmonth); /*write the var value in the selected cell preview positioned by the function onSearch*/
   daypos.setValue(remspacestxtday); 
}

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("Page");
}

function onSearch(form){
    var tempc = form.comites;
    var comite = tempc.trim();
    /*Browser.msgBox(comite);*/
    var searchString = comite;
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("REYNOSA"); 
    var column =4; //column Index - where i am going to search the value of the var comite 
    var columnValues = sheet.getRange(2, column, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues(); //1st cell Titles
    var searchResult = columnValues.findIndex(searchString); //Cell Index - 2

    if(searchResult != -1)
    {
        //searchResult + 2 is row index.
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().setActiveRange(sheet.getRange(searchResult + 2, 1))
    }
}

Array.prototype.findIndex = function(search){
  if(search == "") return false;
     for (var i=0; i<this.length; i++)
       if (this[i] == search) return i;
  return -1;
 } 

Array.prototype.findIndex = function(search){
  if(search == "") return false;
     for (var i=0; i<this.length; i++)
         if (this[i] == search) return i;
  return -1;
}
```

> page.html

```
<head>

    <title>Page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>

         <form>
          INGRESA LA FECHA DE ENTREGA QUE DESEAS UTILIZAR PARA LOS COMITES...  /EN/...WRITE THE DATE YOU ARE GOING TO USE TO CAPTURE THE RECEIPTS
         <br><br/>
            <select id="monthlist" name="monthlist">
            <option value="enero">JANUARY</option>
            <option value="febrero">FEBRUARY</option>
            <option value="marzo">MARCH</option>
            <option value="abril">APRIL</option>
            <option value="mayo">MAY</option>
            <option value="Junio">JUNE</option>
            <option value="julio">JULY</option>
            <option value="agosto">AUGUST</option>
            <option value="septiembre">SEPTEMBER</option>
            <option value="octubre">OCTOBER</option>
            <option value="noviembre">NOVEMBER</option>
            <option value="diciembre">DECEMBER</option>
            </select>
         <br><br/>
            Ingresa el MES [EJEMPLO: MARZO]: /EN/WRITE THE MONTH <input id="resp" type="text" value="" name="mesinini" />
         <br><br/>
            Ingresa el DIA /EN/WRITE THE DAY OF THE MONTH [EJEMPLO: 14]: <input id="resp" type="text" value="" name="dias" />
         <br><br/>
            CAPTURA EL COMITE. /EN/ CAPTURE THE RECEIPT NUMBER
         <br><br/>
            Ingresa el Comite: /EN/ WRITE THE RECEIPT NUMBER <input id="resp" type="text" value="" name="comites" />
         <br><br/>
            <input type="button" onclick="formautomd()" value="Capturar Entrega del Comite"/> /*THIS BUTTON*/
         <br><br/>         
            <input type="button" onclick="formonSearch()" value="Buscar Comite"/> 
         <br><br/>
            <input type="button" onclick="formexit()" value="Salir del Menu"/>
       </form>
     </div>  
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function formonSearch() {
               /////even tried to put the getElementbyId here and same result.
        google.script.run.onSearch(document.forms[0]);
    }
    function formautomd() {
        google.script.run.autowritemonthday(document.forms[0]);
        } /* IT NEED BE STORAGED WHEN I PRESS THIS BUTTON*/
    function formexit(){
        google.script.host.close();
        }
</script>
```

Comment: While it may not be necessary, it would help if you translated your variable names into English, so that it's easier for people to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am really sorry, I just done that. Hope can help me.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById()` can not be used in `.gs` server code.  The `.gs` script runs on Google's servers.  `getElementById()` only works in the browser.  Your function:

```
function autowritemonthday(form){
   var storeMonth = getElementById('monthlist').value; 
  /*Does not work i dont know why*/
```

Is in the `.gs` code.  `getElementById()` only works in a `<script>` tag in HTML.

The data you want must come from the 'form' object.

This is what you need to use:

```
var storeMonth = form["monthlist"];
```

To see what is in your form object, iterate through the form object like this:

```
function autowritemonthday(form){
  Logger.log('form: ' + form);

  for (var key in form) {
    Logger.log('the key is: ' + key);
    Logger.log('the value is: ' + form[key]);
  };

  return;
};
```

Submit the form, then in the code editor, choose the VIEW menu, and then LOGS.

My original answer:

Did you try something like this:

```
function formautomyd() {
  var storeMonth = getElementById('monthlist').value;
  google.script.run.autofechaydia(document.forms[0]);
}
```

You stated that you used:

```
getElementByID
```

But didn't show the code.  The letter "D" on the end can't be capitalized.  Must be lower case.  `getElementById()`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time, but I had tried that in several ways putting on PAge.gs and html page but it doesnot popup the value of the var in the msgbox, I update my code here and put that example but nothing happens I do not know why, It is funny because if i tried this in my localhost it works i do not whats happend, I am getting other values but by name from inputbox and works great but when i use getElementById my code does nothing, Maybe i can Share my Google Document and get help in my live code.